# How to validate model with eclipselink jpa

Tags: java, jpa, model, eclipselink, bean-validation

I hava a model, and i need to validate model with [eclipselink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) jpa
and i add anotation @NotEmpty validate name if empty, but when i save/persist model, validate not work

```
  @Entity
    public class Role {

        @Id
        private String id;
        @NotEmpty
        private String name;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }
```

my jpa configuration xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="Eclipselink_JPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>app.test.Model.Role</class>

        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>


        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JPA API (which `EclipseLink` implements) is nothing to do with the [Bean Validation API](http://beanvalidation.org/). 
To utilise the Bean Validation API you need the Bean Validation API jar (javax.validation), together with an implementation of that API (`Apache BVAL`, `Hibernate Validator`, etc) in your CLASSPATH. 
The only thing JPA provides is to auto-enable validation as per [this link](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/persistence.html#bean_validation), but the default is "auto" so nothing required really for that

Comment: solved with  Hibernate Validator and javax validation